# ExecuteRequest is Obsolete, How should we derive from the ExecuteRequest pipeline processor?

Tags: pipelines

So recently noticed a compiler warning on a custom pipeline I wrote to override what pages "Page Not Found", "Layout Not Found" get redirected to (in order to make them site specific pages in a mutlisite solution).

> 'ExecuteRequest.ExecuteRequest()' is obsolete: 'Use another
>   constructor overload with dependency injection.`

Any thoughts on how to properly implement these types of redirects now?

Comment: Pretty sure this one covers it all. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items

Comment: ExecuteRequest Handles Layout Not Found, Site Access Denied, Redirect to Login Page, plus I give the ability to configure different custom pages at a site level, so each site can customize the page it redirects to.

Comment: How are you using it in code?

Comment: Just extending it and overriding the methods: e.g. MultiSitePageConfigurationPipeline : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking this to Slack - here was the problem. In the base class, the default constructor is using poor mans DI to resolve the references:

```
[Obsolete("Use another constructor overload with dependency injection.")]
public ExecuteRequest()
  : this(ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BaseSiteManager>(), ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BaseItemManager>())
{
}
```

In the derived class, you need to have a constructor setup that injects the required dependencies and passes those through to the base class, like this:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : ExecuteRequest
{
    public MyDerivedClass(BaseSiteManager baseSiteManager, BaseItemManager baseItemManager)
     : this(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)
    {
    }
}
```

Now the derived class is calling the new constructor in the base class and injecting the dependencies correctly.

Comment: This was the problem. Adding the constructor removed the compiler warning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The derived processor needs `resolve="true"` set where this patch config takes place.