# How to derive from the obsolete ExecuteRequest pipeline processor

Tags: pipelines, upgrade

We are upgrading to SC9.3. A custom class `UserRequestProcessor` which inherits from `ExecuteRequest` has errors now, as the new `ExecuteRequest` class in not a parameterless constructor anymore.

The solution provided [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/executerequest-is-obsolete-how-should-we-derive-from-the-executerequest-pipelin) did not work.

```
public class UserRequestProcessor : ExecuteRequest
{
        public UserRequestProcessor(BaseSiteManager baseSiteManager, BaseItemManager baseItemManager)
            : this(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)

        {
        }
}
```

There is an error at `this` in the constructor, which says:

> UserRequestProcessor.UserRequestProcessor(BaseSiteManager
>   baseSiteManager, BaseItemManager baseItemManager) cannot call itself.

How to modify the custom class to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:**
Changing `this` to `base` fixed the issue and does not give any build errors.
However, deploying the code, there was an error:

> Could not create instance of type:
>   Sitecore.Foundation.RequestFilter.Pipeline.UserRequestProcessor. No
>   matching constructor was found.

To fix that, I had to add `resolve="true"` in the patch config like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestProcessed>
        <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']"
          type="Sitecore.Foundation.RequestFilter.Pipeline.UserRequestProcessor, Sitecore.Foundation.RequestFilter" resolve="true"/>
      </httpRequestProcessed>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Use `base(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)` instead of `this(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to call

```
: this(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)
```

as that would mean you have recursive call to your `UserRequestProcessor` contructor again and that would mean infinite loop.

What you want to do is to call

```
: base(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)
```

which means "call the base class constructor with parameters `(baseSiteManager, baseItemManager)`.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the build issue but on deployment it threw an error. To fix it, I had to add `resolve="true"` in the patch config for the processor setting. Updated the same in the question.