# How do you restrict media from serving up on different domains in SXA?

Tags: sxa

Let's say for example we have two SXA websites.

- AwesomeSauce.com
- TheBomb.com

If an image appears on one domain, I can access it using the other domain.

```html
https://www.awesomesauce.com/-/media/project/awesome/sauce/usa/images/hero.jpg?
https://www.thebomb.com/-/media/project/awesome/sauce/usa/images/hero.jpg?
```

Is there a way to restrict the tenant content to a specific domain?

Comment: SXA does not provide such functionality out of the box.

Comment: Nor does basic Sitecore I might add

Answer (score 3):

What about doing this with domains and security.

You can setup domains for your sites - let's call them `awesomesource` and `thebomb`.

Then in your media library, deny access to the sections specific for each site to the other sites domain anonymous user.

So on the `/sitecore/media library/project/awesome/sauce/` deny access to `thebomb\anonymous` and vice versa on `/sitecore/media library/project/the/bomb/` for `awesomesource\anonymous`.

It would not stop content editors from selecting the wrong image. But it would then give a 401 error. You could also customize that to generate a 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept in Sitecore and, I suspect, no such concept in SXA. But here's how I would approach it (generally speaking):

- add a new custom attribute to your `<site>` definitions; like `mediaRoot="/sitecore/media library/awesomesauce"` and `mediaRoot="/sitecore/media library/thebomb"`
- Using existing handling for 404 of Media Items (found elsewhere on this site), expand that with a check for the image being served. If the image is not `.IsDescendantOf` the `mediaRoot` you defined, 404 it
- Profit in powerful ways

Reference: [How do you setup a 404 and 500 error page for missing files and media items?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items)

Caveat: There would be no UI support. Likely you would need to consider something like a custom image field validator or so - but even so, the Information Model in Sitecore does not easily lend itself to this approach. Who is to tell, whether a datasource item living somewhere in shared space, will be presented on Site A or Site B.

Comment: I think you could skip the step with the custom attribute. Media root for SXA site can be obtained from site root item (there is a field with a link to site-specific root under media).

Comment: Ah right. Even better then :-)