# Locate web.config to implement 404 page

Tags: sitecore-client, configuration

I'm really new with Sitecore and I'm not sure where to perform this change. So far I only know the CMS web interface which is very limited. How can I locate the web.config file? What tool should I use? Should I connect Visual Studio with the site or should I perform a remote desktop connection?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS where your website is hosted and running. Open your website in explorer and you should be able to locate web config file. Path may look like below.

~\WWWRoot\"YourSiteInstance"\

Alternatively, You can have a look at all the configs by running below link in the browser.

https://"YourSiteInstance"/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

To setup 404, visit below link

[How do you setup a 404 and 500 error page for missing files and media items?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items)

Comment: This has been really helpful, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For location, just open IIS, locate your website and in the right pane click explore.

[image]

Just to get your started down the right path, you never ever want to edit the web.config directly. You want to use a tool like [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) and transform your web.config, adding/removing what you need. If you edit it directly, it makes upgrading and deploying more difficult. Below I believe is the transform you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="403" />
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="500" responseMode="Redirect" path="/500.html" />
            <error statusCode="403" responseMode="Redirect" path="/404.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="/404.html" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```