# 200 error on a bad URL request

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api, url-rewrite

Well this is weird, we have a `Sitecore 9.1` multisite, and when someone tries to access
https://www.abc.com/www.cc.com/ it is redirecting to `200` status code but with a server error message but if I remove `www. -- .com` and keep only https://www.abc.com/cc/ it gives custom error page with page not found error message. I tried to find any solutions for this in blogs but could not find any. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The request with /www.cc.com (without trailing slash) is handled at the IIS level and IIS considers it as a file in the file system and it returns the IIS error if not present. If you add trailing slash, Sitecore will return the error. What kind of server error are you seeing when you browse path with dots?

Comment: There is a custom error HTML page which is shown to the user if user tries to access https://www.abc.com/www.cc.com/  and if he tries to browse only https://www.abc.com/cc/ , user is shown a 500 error page which is served from ErrorHandler code but this code never gets executed when I browse https://www.abc.com/www.cc.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you setup a 404 and 500 error page for missing files and media items?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items) This is a very helpful post and discussion that explains why it happens and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please write a custom url handler, there you can handle the paramter you are receiving and redirect to 404 as and when required.

https://www.altudo.co/resources/blogs/how-to-create-sitecore-custom-urls-diy-guide

Best Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).